C# app connecting to Maria DB using Mysqlconnector return "Authentication method 'dialog' is not supported"
I'm trying to connect to MariaDB from c# application. I use Mysqlconnector nuget package. I created simple app base on tutorial:
string connectionString = "Server=xxx;Port=3306;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;Database=xxx";

using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
}

I get exception:

Authentication method 'dialog' is not supported

I was trying to debug this package and i found out that this exception is thrown on establishing connection to DB even before credentials are used for authentication.
regards

Can you try the MySql.Data package? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-string.html

Check your DB config server: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pluggable-authentication-overview/ It seams u use "dialog" as an authentication plugin.

@hakim00 tried MySql.Data and i get almost same exception

@DA is there possibility to change something on client side? I'm not the owner of MariaDB server and any changes there would be hard

Why is the user in the database created to use the dialog plugin?

Check setting on following including the Next Page.  The advance Tab has option "Enable Cleartext Authentication Plugin"  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-manage-server-connections.html
